Are there other Marvel easter egg props in the "Deadpool & Wolverine" hideout?
In Deadpool & Wolverine (2024), there's a scene where Deadpool and Wolverine are in the hideout of Marvel characters that were originally not in the MCU:

 Elektra, Blade, Gambit, and X-23.

In the hideout, I noticed that the bed Deadpool wakes up on—whose frame is a large creature's lower jaw and teeth—is the same bed Hulk had in Thor: Ragnarok (2017).


I also spotted a statue of the Scarlet Witch from Doctor Strange in the Multiverse of Madness (2022).

Aside from these two, are there other easter eggs props in their lair that reference previous Marvel works? To clarify, I'm not talking about items like

 Elektra's sais, Blade's sword, or Gambit's cards.

Instead, I'm interested in background elements that might only be noticed by fans familiar with earlier Marvel movies from which those elements originally appeared.
